# Qt - Reading csv document to QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, csv

I have a csv document with different inputs, and I only want the first entry in every row. Therefore I tried my way with a subString, by setting a ":" as the first() delimiter. But the program reads every entry twice, what am I doing wrong?

[image: Sreenshot of program]

[image: Screenshot of CSV document]

```
if (getin.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {

    items = getin.readAll();

     rowOfData = items.split("\n");
     getin.close();

}
for (int x = 0; x < rowOfData.size(); x++)
{
    rowData = rowOfData.at(x).split(",").first().split(":");


    for (int y = 0; y < rowData.size(); y++)
    {
        ui->itemListWidget->addItem(rowData.first());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the last loop. The list rowData contains 2 elements (eg ["Chocolate", "on maj 2016"]), and you iterate over the list taking always the first element, so you create two items.
Yuo don't need to iterate over the list, simply take the first element once.

Example

```
if(!rowData.isEmpty)
    ui->itemListWidget->addItem(rowData.first());
```

Comment: I put in this line: if(!rowData.isEmpty()), but the output in the program is the same.
EDIT - I removed the second for loop, and it works.

Comment: but you have to remove tthe loop! (replace for (int y = 0; y < rowData.size(); y++) )